# React-bootstrap button bsStyle

Tags: react-bootstrap

Ok, I am missing something obviously but cannot figure it now.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
let App=React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
            <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">Primary</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="success">Success</Button>
            <Button>Sketo</Button>
             </div>
        );
    }

});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I can see the buttons but there are not styles applied to them. Thay are all plain as the third one. Grey and small. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the App component works OK~, it has no problem when I test.
Maybe you miss one thing: To link in the CSS of Bootstrap.
Try to add a linking stylesheet inside the head of the HTML.

Comment: I knew it was something easy like this. Thank you for you time answering!

Comment: yup, the react-bootstrap package dosent contain any style sheet. :)