# Simple button not showing

Tags: meteor, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to just get off the ground with Meteor 1.2.1 and am failing miserably.

I've simply used the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302202/react-bootstrap-button-bsstyle) but always receive a blank page. If I remove the Button class, there's no problem with getting the div to appear or text inside it.

I receive no console errors.

My added packages:

- twbs:bootstrap            3.3.6
- universe:react-bootstrap  0.24.0
- react                     0.14.3*

Code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

Meteor.startup(function () {
    let App=React.createClass({

        render: function () {
            return (
                <div>
                      <Button>Default</Button>
                </div>
            );
        }

    });
    React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("container"));
});
```

}

I expect that whatever I'm missing is very simple, but can't narrow it down other then reac-bootstrap being the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you `require`/`import` the `Button` component anywhere in your code? Maybe that's what was missing.

Comment: You were on the right track.  Within the app's .jsx, I had to include `let { Button } = ReactBootstrap;`, otherwise it's `import { Button } from 'bootstrap';` within *.import.jsx files ( as per the universe: documentation.  go figure)

Answer (score 0):

In my ignorance, I simply did not follow the [universe:react-bootstrap documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/universe/react-bootstrap).

> As a global
>
> This package additionally export ReactBootstrap as a global, so you
>   can write inside any .jsx file:
>
> `let { Button } = ReactBootstrap;`
>
> `<Button /> // React component`
>
> or
>
> `<ReactBootstrap.Button /> // React component`

```
let { Button } = ReactBootstrap;

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.startup(function () {

        let App=React.createClass({

            render: function () {
                return (
                  <div>
                      <Button>Default</Button>
                  </div>
                );
            }

        });
        React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("container"));
    });

}
```