# React Bootstrap button looking faded

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I used the

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">Primary</Button>
```

Unlike the question here [React-bootstrap button bsStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302202/react-bootstrap-button-bsstyle) , I have included the bootstrap css in the root html page.

I am unable to figure the issue.

Here is my code

**Index.ejs**
Css file :

**Component.jsx:**

```
import {Button, Col, Glyphicon, Label, OverlayTrigger, Row, Table, Tooltip} from "react-bootstrap";


<Button href={version.downloadUri} bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">
```

Primary button

**Main issue:**
I do see the button and I also think that the css is being applied cause when I hover over the button, it looks normal. The button on the other hand in its natural state looks faded.

Comment: Could you show your css file ?

Comment: if you included the bootstrap css in the root html page, you should put to button tag className="primary" to take the style.

Comment: Nope , that doesn't do the trick. I have explained the reason for my problem in an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to finally figure out the issue today when I had the time today. It is a bit tough to accept but the href attribute is what caused the css to not be applied.

This surely was strange considering the fact that it is a prop that is officially supported and mentioned in the react-bootstrap docs here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#buttons-props . On looking deeper at the code that's finally the output using inspect element in chrome, it turns out that the href caused the  component to be rendered as an anchor tag. So basically the css was being applied but to an anchor tag. This was the main issue. Hence I just wrapped the anchor tag around the button and now it works perfectly. I still don't know what the actual cause was. I created a small snippet of something similar on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/zrue0aa1/21/ and it works. 
In case anyone else faces this issue , my final code for the button is this:

```
<a href={version.downloadUri}>
                        <Button className="primary" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large"
                                disabled={version.version === null}>
                            <span>Download
                            </span><br/>
                            <span>
                              Version : {version.version === null ? "Null" : version.version}
                            </span>
                        </Button>
                        </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Herewith attaching screenshot of button. It is behaving as normal as it gets. Probably you are messing something in css. However I used react-bootstrap and here what I got:

[image]

Could you post your button's screenshot ?